# Scrolling bad practice for UICollectionViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I made a horizontal scrolling UICollectionView and I want the cell that's in the middle to have a white font while the rest is black.

If I just use scrollViewDidEndDecelerating highlighting of the middle cell seems to jump around more than if I use both scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating to highlight the middle cell. Is this bad practice?

```
extension CurrencySelectorTableViewCell: UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.findCenterIndex()
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.findCenterIndex()
    }
}
```

This code btw still doesn't animate perfectly like I want it to so I'm open to any advice how to make this scrolling mechanism as smooth as possible.

When the UICollectionView thus starts scrolling this function is triggered:

```
func findCenterIndex() {
    let center = self.convert(self.collectionView.center, to: self.collectionView)
    let index = collectionView!.indexPathForItem(at: center)

    if let selectedIndex = index {
        self.selectedCell = selectedIndex.item
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Upon reloading the UICollectionView the label in the cell that is located in the middle will look different from the rest:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CurrencySelectorCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CurrencySelectorCollectionViewCell

    if (indexPath.item == self.selectedCell) {
        cell.currencyLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        cell.currencyLabel.font = cell.currencyLabel.font.withSize(22)
    } else {
        cell.currencyLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.currencyLabel.font = cell.currencyLabel.font.withSize(15)
    }

    cell.currencyLabel.text = currencies[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

Right now it jumps around a little bit because it will only change the label when the scrolling has just started or just stopped. I would like this effect on the UITextLabel to happen continuously throughout the scrolling process.

Comment: Animate? You are saying that you are **highlighting** a cell, but later you say that you are firing animations, which is it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Right now I'm just changing the text color of the UILabel in the UICollectionCell based on which cell is in the middle. I prefer to animate this effect as user scrolls through the horizontally spread out UICollectionCells.

Comment: @rutgerHujismans can you add your animation code that you are firing?

Comment: @rutgerhujismans check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add [removeAllAnimations()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410810-removeallanimations) of your `UILabel` layer before you fire off a new animation:

```
[view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

EDIT:

Based on your edit in the question, you are not running any animation. You are calling `reloadData` on your `UICollectionView`, which is really bad practice.

You should just simple either:

**1: (Bad option)**

Reload the Cell only with [performBatchUpdates(_:completion:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates)

**2: Good option**

Access the cell as a variable in your cell `findCenterIndex`with [cellForItem(at:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618088-cellforitem) and simply just do your update to the label.

You can also deselect the other cells by getting an array of the [visibleCells](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618056-visiblecells) and simply just do as same described above, but you fire your "deselection" code instead. You could actually do this before you run your selection code. Or do everything in one action by Simply run a for loop on the visible cells and "deselect" them in your loop, and select the one in your `CGPoint` center.

This way, you **never even have to reload** your UICollectionView and is the best practice. And you also avoid flickers and animations.

Comment: Ok, I'll go for the good option. The reason I opted for reloadData was to reset the label that was previously in the middle.

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans I updated the answer with that solution too. Check it out :)

Comment: ok great thanks this works! I'm not longer reloading the data. The changing of the UILabel still only happens at the end of scrolling movement. This feels a little bit laggy. Is there anyway to make this feel smoother?

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans Sorry forgot to mention You are probably looping it many many many times since this gets fired for every pixel the scrollview moves in your **scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating** method, you need to do some kind of check there to limit the times your custom code and loop gets fired. Either with two properties NSDate and a BOOL checking against NSDate timestamp (maybe allow it only to fire once every 0.5 second from a stored NSDate currentDate, or some other method.

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans Your other option is to just check if the center cell is different from the one before (use a tag or something) and only fire your "animations" if the cell is different or have moved far enough.